# Convert sql view query to hql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jtable, hql

I'm new in Java, so please help if you can.
I need to populate Jtable and I'm doing it with this code:

```
SELECT r.id AS roomID, r.type, r.no_of_rooms, r.no_of_rooms - 
  COALESCE(t.bookedRooms,0) AS available_rooms FROM room AS r  LEFT JOIN (     
  SELECT room_id, SUM(total_rooms) AS bookedRooms   FROM bookings   WHERE 
  `start` < '2017-02-10' AND `ends` > '2017-02-09'   GROUP BY room_id ) AS t 
  ON r.id = t.room_id WHERE r.no_of_rooms - COALESCE(t.bookedRooms,0) > 0
```

and it works like this.

But how can I do this with Hibernate and how to do mapping?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL is a relation-oriented language. HQL and its modern cousin JPQL are object-oriented. One does not simply translate a query from one to the other. Object and data models are really not at alike. Write from the object perspective, _not_ the data perspective when writing JPQL, or the hoary HQL. So do not translate from SQL to JPQL (HQL). Work out your object model and write your object-manipulation queries from that model.